# mod rewrite rule not passing key values

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a few different mod-rewrite rules working, but this last one refuses to pass the 3 parameters to my script (index.php)

I do get the `p=value`, but the `id`, `rid` and `chk` vars don't even get defined...

A URL might look like this . . . .

`http://www.domain.com/pagename.htm?id=29&rid=174&chk=a9cdca614135bbef2fb1f2bedf171f61`

The rule...

```
RewriteRule ^/pagename\.htm\?id\=([0-9]+)&rid\=([0-9]+)&chk\=([a-f0-9]{32})$ /index.php?p=pagename&id=$1&rid=$2&chk=$3 [L]
```

Output of `print_r($_REQUEST);`

```
Array ( [p] => pagename )
```

I simply can not understand why this does not work..

Comment: Do you have to match each of the query string arguments? mod rewrite already has a `QSA` (query string append) flag that will transfer over the query string. So it could just be `RewriteRule ^/pagename\.htm /index.php [L,QSA]` and that should cope the query string to the rewrite.

Comment: rewriterule doesn't include query strings. you need to test that with `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ...`

Comment: I dont think I fully understand..  but yes, I need the p=pagename  part, since it;'s index.php including the "page" which in turn uses the id,rid and chk to perform a database operation

Comment: He is talking about the query string in the original requested url being rewritten. That only includes the page name, not the query string. You have to use a rewrite condition and check the query string in there. If the condition passes, the rule is checked. `RewriteRule [requested url] [rewritten url]`. It is the first one that doesn't include the query string (part including and after the question mark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MarcB said, rewrite rules don't include the query string and you have to use a RewriteCond to check it. This is what would work for you based on your example above:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)&rid=([0-9]+)&chk=([a-f0-9]{32})$
RewriteRule ^pagename.htm index.php?p=pagename&id=%1&rid=%2&chk=%3 [L]
```

Or like I said above, you can also use the `QSA` flag like:

```
RewriteRule ^(pagename).html index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And that will append any additional query string on to index.php, but doesn't validate it (which should REALLY not be done in mod_rewrite). It also allows you to add additional parameters, doesn't require a change of the rules to accommodate them and won't break if the key/values are in different order or case. Note: I added parenthesis around `pagename` and used the match `$1` in the rewritten url. This is so it is easier to change the page name for multiple rules because you don't have to change it in two places.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, I went with your first solution and can now see my vars populated. WOOT !